# Project bundle identifier does not match specified provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, azure-devops, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

For our Xamarin.Forms mobile app, after upgrading to iOS 15, I created a new certificate and provisioning profile. Build in Azure DevOps failed with the following error:

> Info.plist : error : Project bundle identifier 'com.somename.Somename' does not match specified provisioning profile '2C13822C-583A-40FD-A418-28F2C2CAF228'

I changed the bundle identifier in Info.plist to the same guid as in the provisioning profile. But build failed again with this error:

> Project bundle identifier '2C13822C-583A-40FD-A418-28F2C2CAF228' does not match specified provisioning profile '2C13822C-583A-40FD-A418-28F2C2CAF228'

Restored back to com.somename.Somename.

How can this be explained, and what else am I missing?

Comment: *"I changed the bundle identifier in Info.plist to the same guid as in the provisioning profile."* Sorry I'm not familiar with Azure DevOPs so can't help - but definitely DO NOT do that. Keep the original bundle identifier. That must NEVER change for your app. And it should look like `com...` as you showed originally. I recommend deleting that provisioning profile, and any others on your mac, and creating a new one. And going very carefully through those steps: when you created it, did it show the correct bundle identifier - the one that worked before you upgraded?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you for your comment. I will restore the bundle identifier, like you said. I did recreate the provisioning profile, but don't know what identifier the previous profile had...

Comment: This link(https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/97438) may hlep you.

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT Thank you for the link. It is stated there, "In essence everything was setup the way it should when it comes to the provisioning profile and certificate side of things, the only bit missing was the default bundle id that needed to be changed in accordance to the provisioning file." But it does not tell how it should be changed. As I mentioned, my attempt to change it had not helped, and ToolmakerSteve in his comment insisted I was not supposed to do that.

Comment: Its a somewhat misleading error message. The bundle identifier is unique to your app. It never changes, after first publish. It has the format com.your company.yourapp. Not a guid. When I said not to change it, I meant not to that guid - and if it had been working before the upgrade, then it was already correct in info.plist. To be sure: You can see its value by logging into apple connect MyApps and going to that app. Is that same as in your info.plist?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Oh, OK. As I mentioned, I did restore the bundle identifier, as you said. I checked at Apple Connect, and it is the same as I have in info.plist. Don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hmm. Feels like its picking up a different provisioning profile than the one you just downloaded. [Find where profile is stored in Finder, and delete ALL profiles you see there, then download again.] Ah, I haven't used Azure DevOps. Automatic provisioning?Some disconnect between Microsoft Azure or XF, and Apple's instructions. Related to using a new certificate. Even though its (almost certainly) not an Apple problem per se, I would contact Apple support, explain the setup, see if they can advise you what to try.

Comment: Or try Azure support. Alternatively, do it without Azure DevOps. On VS Mac, manual provisioning - do everything directly on that Mac. (Can be done from VS on Windows with a build Mac - but iirc its simpler to go straight to the Mac itself, get everything correct there.) OR delete the Azure project (task? pipeline?) for your app, create it again with the new certificate.